# Unable to install any plugins on jenkins on Mac OS X- (SHA-256 match error)

Tags: java, jenkins, jenkins-plugins, hudson, sha256

Am getting the following error when I try to download any plugin. This is a new development and didn't seem to happen earlier. I installed Jenkins using brew. I tried multiple reinstalls but nothing seems to work.

Also I noticed that my actual SHA-256 value is always '47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU=', irrespective of the plugin. Makes me think it is a error with how my machine is generating the SHA.

```
java.io.IOException: Downloaded file /Users/madhav/.jenkins/plugins/trilead-api.jpi.tmp does not match expected SHA-256, expected 'aRsCZA5PqYAxMhX6G+AXjA7yZArlzU0+MCEUEo1oVd8=', actual '47DEQpj8HBSa+/TImW+5JCeuQeRkm5NMpJWZG3hSuFU='
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.throwVerificationFailure(UpdateCenter.java:2025)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter.verifyChecksums(UpdateCenter.java:2060)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob.replace(UpdateCenter.java:2239)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$UpdateCenterConfiguration.install(UpdateCenter.java:1343)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:1872)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$InstallationJob._run(UpdateCenter.java:2153)
    at hudson.model.UpdateCenter$DownloadJob.run(UpdateCenter.java:1843)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at hudson.remoting.AtmostOneThreadExecutor$Worker.run(AtmostOneThreadExecutor.java:118)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

I tried to genetate the checksum of all the `*.jpi.tmp` files in my `.jenkins` folder and got a different checksum. Also all those files where empty.

```
madhav@Madhavs-MacBook-Pro.local /Users/madhav/.jenkins/plugins 
% shasum -a 256 structs.jpi.tmp
e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  structs.jpi.tmp
madhav@Madhavs-MacBook-Pro.local /Users/madhav/.jenkins/plugins 
% shasum -a 256 workflow-durable-task-step.jpi.tmp

e3b0c44298fc1c149afbf4c8996fb92427ae41e4649b934ca495991b7852b855  workflow-durable-task-step.jpi.tmp
```

Comment: Crete an empty, zero byte file and see if the checksum is the same

Comment: hey @IanW I have updated my question with more info regarding the same, the checksum for a 0 byte file is different

Comment: what version of jenkins do you use, this seems like a jenkins defect, did you check for issues in jenkins version that you are using?

Comment: @Saravanan I am using jenkins 2.266. I did see some similar issues online, but most of them were chalked up as user system problems. I have also tried other versions like the LTS 2.249.3 but. am still facing the same issue.

Comment: Also when I start jenkins in my terminal I see ```WARNING: Illegal reflective access by jenkins.model.AssetManager (file:/Users/madhav/.jenkins/war/WEB-INF/lib/jenkins-core-2.266.jar) to method java.lang.ClassLoader.findResource(java.lang.String)
``` Can this be the problem?

Comment: this might have some issues. did you try running the jenkins command using root access (sudo)?

Comment: I did try with sudo, but getting the same issue

Comment: See Jenkins [INFRA-2815](https://issues.jenkins.io/browse/INFRA-2815)

Comment: Got it thanks @IanW !